# How do I reset the stream of StdOut in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, stdout, ping

I want to use a VB script (full script in the [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kenUXybK)) to check that certain servers are up (responding to pings) every time I log in to my work computer.

However, it seems that as I am grabbing the full results of the output...

```
strPingResultsFull = LCase(WshExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
```

...before I loop through the individual lines...

```
Do Until WshExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
```

...that `WshExec.StdOut` is already `AtEndOfStream`, so I'm never getting any results.

The first part of my questing - is this theory correct (or likely to be correct)? The second part - How do I sort this out (i.e. reset the stream so that I can check every line individually)? Thanks.

```
' Set the targets to ping
strTarget(0) = "192.168.1.6"    ' TTSA
strTarget(1) = "192.168.1.7"    ' TTSB
strTarget(2) = "192.168.1.14"   ' TTSC
strTarget(3) = "192.168.1.12"   ' TTSD

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Loop through all of the targets to ping
For i = 0 To UBound(strTarget)

    ' Ping the target
    Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 500 " & strTarget(i)) ' Send 2 echo requests, waiting 0.5 seconds maximum

    ' Grab the full results of the ping
    strPingResultsFull = LCase(WshExec.StdOut.ReadAll)

    ' Set 'strPingResultsPart' to an empty string
    strPingResultsPart = ""

    ' Grab the results of the ping
    Do Until WshExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream

        strSingleLine = WshExec.StdOut.ReadLine()
        If Instr(strSingleLine, "Ping statistics for") <> 0 Or Instr(strSingleLine, "Packets:") <> 0 Then
            strPingResultsPart = strPingResultsPart & strSingleLine
        End If

    Loop

    ' Check that there is something to output (there should be, even if the pings all fail)
    If strPingResultsPart <> "" Then

        Msgbox "Not empty - " & strPingResultsPart
        ' Add the ping results to the correct results strings
        If InStr(strPingResultsFull, "reply from") Then     
            strOutputSuccess = strOutputSuccess & strPingResultsPart & VBCrLf
        Else
            strOutputFailure = strOutputFailure & strPingResultsPart & VBCrLf
        End If

    End If

    Set WshExec = Nothing

Next
```

Comment: If `strPingResultsFull` is populated correctly, why do not you `Split()` the output and iterate over the resulting array?

Comment: Hmm, could do I suppose. Didn't think of it that way! Will do some testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After first call `WshExec.StdOut.ReadAll` you're already at `AtEndOfStream` therefore...

```
Do Until WshExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
```

...will do nothing. You can't seek back `StdOut` to read from it multiple times.

Comment: I figured that is why it was doing nothing, so the bulk of the question was how to rewind (reset the stream). It's a pity you can't do it, but I was able to build the complete output whilst looping through each line in this instance. Thanks.